# Should I pass data to a modal as an argument?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this code

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of bitacoraDat" name="item">
    <ion-item>
        <strong>Descripción:</strong> {{item.descripcion}}
        <button (click)="openModal(item)" slot="end">
            <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <strong>Encargado:</strong> {{item.encargado}}

    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <strong>Fecha:</strong> {{item.created}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Is it right to pass specific data as argument of the method? what am i missing? if ot how do it do it? I know that i must put them in componentProps but what if i want to send an specific id?

Here is where I open it

```
    async openModal(item) {
    console.log('item bit' + item);

    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalPage,
        componentProps: {
            bitacoraDat: item
        }
    });
    await modal.present();
}
```

The code returns item bit[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass whatever you want, the input you got its ok,
You can also print some object's property to know what you've passed.

```
 async openModal(item) {
    console.log('item bit' + item.id, item.otrapropiedad);
 ...
```

The **[object Object]**  you got in your console log is beacause js its concat an string **'item bit'** to and object **item** so the object should be converted to string.

The right way to print the above

```
console.log('item bit' , item)
```

Saludos.

Comment: Is there an option to pass the entire object and not variabe by variable??

Comment: Yes , as you did 
 componentProps: {
            bitacoraDat: item
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private modalController: ModalController, public navParams: NavParams) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.item = this.navParams.get('item');
    console.log(this.navParams.get('item'));
}
```

The right way to get the data is with this

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your object like this

**componentProps: { bitacoraDat: yourObj}**

if its still showing issue just do this

**componentProps: { bitacoraDat: JSON.stringify(yourObj)}**

when you want to use it just to JSON.parse